# everything compiles but i dont get any kind of feed back as if the main is not calling the functions does anyone know why?

Tags: c

i have tested each part individually and i know they work the problem is when i paste the function roll_dice back in or vise verse.When i compile the two together i get the error C2143 missing ';' before 'type' on line 32 which is the play_game function. can someone tell me why im getting this error when they work separately but do not work when they are put together. This is a craps game and i am a beginner at using c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_DIE 6
#define true 1
#define false 0

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int roll = 0;
int point = 0;
int wins = 0;
int losses = 0;
int keep_rolling = 1;

int main(void)
{

  void roll_dice(int num1, int num2, int roll);
  {
    srand(time(NULL ));
    num1 = ("%d", rand() % MAX_DIE + 1);
    num2 = ("%d", rand() % MAX_DIE + 1);
    roll = (num1 + num2);
    printf("this is your number : %d\n", num1);
    printf("this is your 2nd number : %d\n", num2);
    printf("this is your total : %d\n", roll);
  }

  void play_game(int wins, int losses, int point, int roll);
  {

    if ((roll == 7) || (roll == 11))
    {
      printf("you rolled %d you won \n", roll);
      wins += 1;
    }
    else if ((roll == 2) || (roll == 3) || (roll == 12))
    {
      printf("you rolled %d you lost \n", roll);
      losses += 1;
    }
    else if ((roll == 1) || (roll == 4) || (roll == 5) || (roll == 6)
        || (roll == 8) || (roll == 9) || (roll == 10))
    {
      printf("you have pointed : %d\n", roll);
      point = roll;
      printf("you rolled %d you pointed \n", roll);

      while (keep_rolling = 1)
      {
        void roll_dice(int num1, int num2, int roll);

        if (roll == point)
        {
          printf("you rolled %d you won \n", roll);
          wins += 1;
          return keep_rolling = false;
        }
        else if (roll == 7)
        {
          printf("you rolled %d you lost \n", roll);
          losses += 1;
          return keep_rolling = false;
        }
        else
        {
          printf("you rolled : %d\n", roll);
          printf("your point is : %d\n", point);
        }
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the method in main, you have only declared it.

Comment: the above that is in bold is a typo an not the problem sorry for the inconvenience. the issue that i am having is explained in the paragraph above the code

Comment: You should invest in a decent C tutorial, there are some major misunderstandings of how functions work in the above code which are hard to sensibly address in a Q&A format without the answer being "it's just all wrong" which is frustrating to have to write, and not very helpful or enlightening to you. Going through a tutorial and sticking to simpler things for a while would probably be best.

Comment: @stevenHelsell: Please don't radically change the code in your question like this, it makes all the people who gave you answers appear to be insane.

Comment: What do you expect a line like `num1 = ("%d", rand() % MAX_DIE + 1);` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `functions` outside `main()` function and call functions from `main()`

You should not define functions inside `main()`.

You have added semicolons while `defining` them. remove semicolons at the end.

Also `declare` functions above `main()`

Read functions [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson4.html) [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_using_functions.htm) and [Here](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-functions-and-global-local-variables)

Comment: im not sure what that looks like im researching it and everything i have tryed comes back with errors  saying im missing function header

Comment: which errors are you getting ?  what are the changes have made ? and are you getting logical errors or else compilation or run time errors ? did you gone through with the links ? did you USE debugger?

Comment: im using notepad++ and looking through the links you posted at functions.

Comment: ok i tried adding:                                                     int play_game(int wins, int losses, int point, int roll);                                           under the define false 0                                                        i took the functions out of main and got rid of the ; behind them and i am taking some of the variables that should be local and added them into the function

Comment: the errors are redefinition of formal peramiter "roll"                   too few arguments to call either of my functions

Comment: Edit your post and add modified code

Comment: thank you with those links i was able to see how badly i created my functions

Answer (score 0):

```
void roll_dice(int num1, int num2, int roll);
```

You can not define function inside an function. It compiled fine in the above case because it is a declaration.